# How to solve Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) on upgrade to joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, upgrade, joomla3.0

I currently have a website on joomla 2.5.27 and I'm planning to upgrade it to joomla 3.3.6 ( latest ). **Immediately after the upgrade to 3.3.6**, I get the following errors:

```
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_mailto, com_mailto, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_wrapper, com_wrapper, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_admin, com_admin, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_banners, com_banners, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_cache, com_cache, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_categories, com_categories, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_checkin, com_checkin, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_contact, com_contact, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_cpanel, com_cpanel, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_installer, com_installer, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_languages, com_languages, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_login, com_login, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_media, com_media, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_menus, com_menus, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_messages, com_messages, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_modules, com_modules, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_newsfeeds, com_newsfeeds, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_plugins, com_plugins, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_search, com_search, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_templates, com_templates, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_weblinks, com_weblinks, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_content, com_content, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_config, com_config, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_redirect, com_redirect, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_users, com_users, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_tags, com_tags, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_contenthistory, com_contenthistory, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_ajax, com_ajax, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (component, com_postinstall, com_postinstall, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, phpmailer, PHPMailer, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, simplepie, SimplePie, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, phputf8, phputf8, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, joomla, Joomla! Platform, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, idna_convert, IDNA Convert, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, fof, FOF, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (library, phpass, PHPass, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_archive, mod_articles_archive, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_latest, mod_articles_latest, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_popular, mod_articles_popular, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_banners, mod_banners, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_breadcrumbs, mod_breadcrumbs, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_custom, mod_custom, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_feed, mod_feed, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_footer, mod_footer, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_login, mod_login, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_menu, mod_menu, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_news, mod_articles_news, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_random_image, mod_random_image, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_related_items, mod_related_items, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_search, mod_search, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_stats, mod_stats, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_syndicate, mod_syndicate, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_users_latest, mod_users_latest, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_weblinks, mod_weblinks, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_whosonline, mod_whosonline, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_wrapper, mod_wrapper, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_category, mod_articles_category, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_articles_categories, mod_articles_categories, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_languages, mod_languages, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_custom, mod_custom, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_feed, mod_feed, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_latest, mod_latest, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_logged, mod_logged, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_login, mod_login, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_menu, mod_menu, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_popular, mod_popular, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_quickicon, mod_quickicon, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_status, mod_status, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_submenu, mod_submenu, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_title, mod_title, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_toolbar, mod_toolbar, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_multilangstatus, mod_multilangstatus, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_stats_admin, mod_stats_admin, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_tags_popular, mod_tags_popular, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (module, mod_tags_similar, mod_tags_similar, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, gmail, plg_authentication_gmail, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, joomla, plg_authentication_joomla, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, ldap, plg_authentication_ldap, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, contact, plg_content_contact, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, emailcloak, plg_content_emailcloak, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, loadmodule, plg_content_loadmodule, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, pagebreak, plg_content_pagebreak, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, pagenavigation, plg_content_pagenavigation, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, vote, plg_content_vote, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, codemirror, plg_editors_codemirror, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, none, plg_editors_none, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, tinymce, plg_editors_tinymce, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, article, plg_editors-xtd_article, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, image, plg_editors-xtd_image, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, pagebreak, plg_editors-xtd_pagebreak, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, readmore, plg_editors-xtd_readmore, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, categories, plg_search_categories, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, contacts, plg_search_contacts, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, content, plg_search_content, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, newsfeeds, plg_search_newsfeeds, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, weblinks, plg_search_weblinks, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, languagefilter, plg_system_languagefilter, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, p3p, plg_system_p3p, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, cache, plg_system_cache, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, debug, plg_system_debug, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, log, plg_system_log, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, redirect, plg_system_redirect, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, remember, plg_system_remember, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, sef, plg_system_sef, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, logout, plg_system_logout, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, contactcreator, plg_user_contactcreator, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, joomla, plg_user_joomla, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, profile, plg_user_profile, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, joomla, plg_extension_joomla, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, joomla, plg_content_joomla, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, languagecode, plg_system_languagecode, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, joomlaupdate, plg_quickicon_joomlaupdate, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, extensionupdate, plg_quickicon_extensionupdate, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, recaptcha, plg_captcha_recaptcha, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, categories, plg_finder_categories, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, contacts, plg_finder_contacts, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, content, plg_finder_content, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, newsfeeds, plg_finder_newsfeeds, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, weblinks, plg_finder_weblinks, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, tags, plg_finder_tags, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, totp, plg_twofactorauth_totp, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (plugin, tags, plg_search_tags, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (template, hathor, hathor, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (language, en-GB, English (United Kingdom), 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (language, en-GB, English (United Kingdom), 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (file, joomla, files_joomla, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (template, isis, isis, 1)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (template, protostar, protostar, 0)
Error on updating manifest cache: (type, element, folder, client) = (template, beez3, beez3, 0)
```

I've uninstalled almost all the 3rd party extensions and left those compatible with joomla 3. The website however seems to work fine ( both frontend and backend ) after the upgrade. So my question is,

**How can I fix this problem ?**
**Does this error create more problems in future, if it persists?**

**What does this error mean ?**

Answer (score 2):

In your Joomla 3.x admin backend, go to:

**System** (top menu) >> **Clear Cache**

Once cleared, go to:

**System** (top menu) >> **Purge Expired Cache**

Once purged, go to:

**Extensions** (top menu) >> **Extension Manager** >> **Database**

and click **Fix** is any errors are appearing

Comment: I followed this article the other day...  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/refresh-manifest-cache-failed ... but didn't work. thanks though.